# How to compute logarithms in Java?

Tags: java, math

Following is the formula

Percentage of Fat = 495 / (1.0324 - 0.19077 x (LOG10(waist - neck)) + 0.15456 x (LOG10(height))) - 450

Following is my code

```
import java.math.*;

public class Position
{
    static double waist=66,neck=30,height=150;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        double fat = 495 / ( (1.0324 - 0.19077)* (Math.log(waist - neck)/Math.log(10)) + (0.15456) *  (Math.log(height)/Math.log(10))) - 450;

        System.out.println(fat);
    }
}
```

The answer I get is incorrect. It should be 11.8% (Use the following http://lowcarbdiets.about.com/library/blbodyfatcalculator.htm )

I believe I have done something incorrectly in logarithms. Please help me to get the correct answer.

Comment: Check the Javadocs. You need to use `Math.log10()`. `Math.log()` returns the logarithm based on `e`

Comment: Even this seems wrong: (1.0324 - 0.19077 x (LOG10(waist - neck)) != ( (1.0324 - 0.19077)* (Math.log(waist - neck)/Math.log(10)), you "override" multiplication precedence from the original formula.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it wouldn't impact the result though

Comment: @eis: but the original formula uses log10 (although I don't know if that is correct).

Comment: You can use *either* Math.log10(x), as @a_horse_with_no_name says, *or* Math.log(x)/Math.log(10), as you are doing, which is equivalent. I don't see any value in the latter, as the former is available, and is closer to what your specification says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have written it incorrectly to code. Try with:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Position
{
    static double waist=66,neck=30,height=150;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        double fat = 495 / ( 1.0324
            - (0.19077 * (Math.log(waist - neck)/Math.log(10)))
            + (0.15456) * (Math.log(height)/Math.log(10))
            ) - 450;

        System.out.println(fat);
    }
}
```

The difference is that this doesn't have `1.0324 - 0.19077` - the original formula didn't have it either, so you had misplaced parenthesis.

As noted by @a_horse_with_no_name, Math.log() will use e-based logarithm, and not 10-based, but in the scope of this code the result is the same. To use 10-based, you'd use Math.log10().

Answer (score 2):

The log calculation is correct but you have misplaced some parenthesis.

```
double fat = 495 / ( 1.0324 - 0.19077* (Math.log(waist - neck)/Math.log(10)) + (0.15456) *  (Math.log(height)/Math.log(10))) - 450
```

Answer (score 1):

```
495 / (1.0324 - 0.19077 x
```

and this

```
495 / ( (1.0324 - 0.19077)*
```

does not match